# Adding view react js on Ruby on Rails API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I build website using Ruby on Rails api only with parameter --api at first step create the project. It work great, but now i want include my view on it (react js). I'm confuse how to implement view on ROR api only.

PS: Why I do this, cz Rails can render html for routes '/' (which is render from .rbenv/.rvm). And I think why not blend Backend(ROR) and Frontend(Reactjs) in same IP and Port

Comment: When you create new apps with `--api ` then your application to start with a more limited set of middleware than normal.
If you want to add a browser feature, just comment `config.api_only = true` at `config/application.rb`.

Comment: and you need two parent controller, example for api : `class ApplicationApiController < ActionController::API` and another parent controller for normal middleware
`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Comment: And name for second controller is application2_controller.rb? @rails_id

Comment: the point of case is not about name of file, but inherits from `ActionController::Base` for the core of a web request and `ActionController::API` for the core of api request.

Comment: Got it. I'm trying that and the output is white screen :(

Comment: you might check out http://ruby-hyperloop.io

Answer (score -1):

Using react router for that I think

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: How to use it in rails?